# psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat: extra data after last expected column, CONTEXT: COPY blog_fbr_data, line 155:

Tags: python, postgresql, insert, export-to-csv

```
    import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(user="user_1",password="test123",host="127.0.0.1",port="5432",database="testdb")
cur = conn.cursor()
with open(r'/home/cybermakarov/Desktop/fbr/download_files/202033095128395ATL_IT.csv', mode='r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='strict', buffering=1) as f:
    # Notice that we don't need the `csv` module.
    #next(f) # Skip the header row.
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)

    #cur.copy 'blog_fbr_data' FROM '/home/cybermakarov/Desktop/fbr/download_files/202033095128395ATL_IT.csv' );


    #database = \COPY ,'blog_fbr_data', from , var = '/home/cybermakarov/Desktop/fbr/download_files/202033095128395ATL_IT.csv', ' CSV HEADER DELIMITER', ',';

    cur.copy_from(f, 'blog_fbr_data', sep=',')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    f.close()
    print("Success commit")
```

> This is my code to insert data from .csv file, it contain more than 150,000 records and I find this solution to solve this problem but when I tried this solution and got the error on line number 155 because that column contain "," in some rows from CSV file which contain bulk data.

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('InActive', 'InActive'),
    ('Active', 'Active'),

)

Vendor_Type = (
    ('Compnay', 'Compnay'),
    ('Individual', 'Individual'),
)


class FBR_Data(models.Model):
    SR_NO = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    NTN_or_CNIC = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100,  null=True, default=' ')
    Business_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, default=' ' )
    #Extended_Business_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default= ' ')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "FbrData"

    def __stf__(self):
        return self.FBR_Data

class Vendors_model(models.Model):
    Client_id = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    Vendor_Number = models.IntegerField()
    Client_Vendor_Type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='InActive')
    Client_Vendor_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Client_Vendor_NTN = models.IntegerField()
    Client_Vendor_Status = models.CharField(max_length=10,  choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='InActive')
    ATL_NTN = models.ForeignKey(FBR_Data, on_delete = models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Fbr_Data', null=True)
    Is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Vendors"

    def __stf__(self):
        return self.Vendors_model





class Fbr_data_and_Vendors_Model(models.Model):
    Id = models.IntegerField()
    fbr_data = models.ForeignKey(FBR_Data, default=1, verbose_name='Fbr_Data', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    vendors_model = models.ForeignKey(Vendors_model, default=1, verbose_name='Vendors', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "fbrData_and_VendorsModel"

    def __stf__(self):
        return self.Fbr_data_and_Vendors_Model
```

> This is model,I tried to save null values as well but it did not worked for me. Please help me to solve this problem. Highly appreciate your contribution to solve this problem.Thank you in advance.

Comment: The csv needs to be fixed, but you have provided no information about how it is generated.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, I could not get your point. I am actually trying to insert data from csv file to Postgress Database.

Comment: would be good if you were able to provide a sample of the file. i think that's what @snakecharmerb is suggesting. also you don't need to explicitly close the file when opening with the context manager and the connection commit/close should be outdented.